# Better visual votebox for answers on search results

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

I would like to recommend a visual change on the search result page for the votebox of answers.
At the moment they look at this:

[image: original]

I think coloring it complete green does look better and is more clean:

[image: new]

I don't know what should happen to the little arrow, maybe remove it?
Also when the votecount is higher then 10000 the alignment breaks. I would say we should rewrite it like it's done on the *flair*, so for example *12513* gets *12.5k* which would fit in the box:

[image: original, fixed]
or

[image: original, shorten]

Comment: `I don't know what should happen to the little arrow` I may be blind, but I don't see an arrow.

Comment: @SantaClaus It's a little hard to see, but I think he's talking about the little gray triangle to the right of the first vote box.

Comment: If nothing else I like the `k` proposal. Who needs to see the exact number when it's got kiloviews?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I think that too. Who cares about 13 votes, when you have 12 thousend of it?