# Missing green box for accepted answers in search

Tags: bug, design, search

When I do a search for questions, those with an accepted answer would have a box with an easy-to-spot green background, and those without an accepted answer would have a transparent background. Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=branch+prediction+is%3Aq
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+python+linked+list+time

Same thing in a user's profile - green background for accepted answer, transparent for non-accepted answer. Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=5
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware?tab=answers

Same for the side bar too:

- [Include the "Has Accepted Answer" shading in the Related sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272075/include-the-has-accepted-answer-shading-in-the-related-sidebar/321501#321501)

However, if I search for answers, there's no green box even for accepted answers. Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+%5Bgit%5D+git+cherry+pick+multiple
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+android+videoview+url

The bad thing is:

1. this is inconsistent with everything else, and
2. this used to work in the old days, [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266449/better-visual-votebox-for-answers-on-search-results). It seems that the green box is gone after [the new styles were implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321413).

Comment: If an answer is accepted, its score is green. But I agree, the text should be a normal color and instead there should be a green box around it.